# Global hook thread takes too much CPU, how to fix?

Tags: delphi

The following global Hook thread is taking too much CPU unless I add Sleep(10) there, 
is there another solution than Sleep(10 ms) - sleeping does not look like an optimal solution for the performance of my application.  If I add too much sleep, doesn't it slow down the mouse too.

```
  procedure THookThread.Execute;
    begin
      hookhandle := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, @LowLevelMouseHook, Hinstance, 0);

     while not Terminated do
      begin    
        MessageLoop;
      //  Sleep(10);
      end;

      UnHookWindowsHookEx(hookhandle);
      hookhandle := 0;

    end;

procedure THookThread.MessageLoop;
var
  msg: TMsg;
begin
  while PeekMessage(msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE) do
  begin
    TranslateMessage(msg);
    DispatchMessage(msg);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Is there any rationale behind 10 ms delay? Typically, abandoning current timeslice is done with `Sleep(0)`.

Comment: Yield instead of sleep(0) should work as well.

Comment: What is the purpose of your thread? And how come you placed your hook in a Thread?

Comment: Why not just use `GetMessage` instead of `PeekMessage`?  The former will naturally block until a message is available, getting around the busy loop and associated high CPU usage.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I would strongly recommend looking for a component that does what you want instead of reinventing this wheel. I myself made good experiences with [GpSysHook](http://17slon.com/gp/gp/gpsyshook.htm)

Comment: I dont see a reason to use component when all this is just a few lines of code.  Reason to use Peekmessage is that Getmessage() does not respond to thread.terminate.    The hook remains alive after thread termination.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something more like this instead:

```
procedure THookThread.Execute;
var
  msg: TMsg;
  ret: LongInt;
begin
  //create the message queue...
  PeekMessage(msg, 0, WM_USER, WM_USER, PM_NOREMOVE);

  hookhandle := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, @LowLevelMouseHook, Hinstance, 0);
  if hookhandle = 0 then RaiseLastOSError; 

  try
    while GetMessage(msg, 0, 0, 0) and (not Terminated) do
    begin
      TranslateMessage(msg);
      DispatchMessage(msg);
    end;
  finally
    UnHookWindowsHookEx(hookhandle);
    hookhandle := 0;
  end;
end;

procedure THookThread.Stop;
begin
  Terminate;
  PostThreadMessage(ThreadID, WM_QUIT, 0, 0);
end;
```

Comment: You can safely treat GetMessage return value as BOOL in this case

Comment: `BOOL` is an alias for `LongBool`, which treats -1 as True. If `GetMessage()` returns -1, and you use a `while GetMessage()` loop, it will not break on a failure. Even MSDN explains that specific condition in the `GetMessage()` documentation and says don't write your code that way. Hence the explicit check for -1 (especially since I want to call `RaiseLastOSError()` anyway, as `GetLastError()` reports an error code when `GetMessage()` returns -1).

Comment: The docs say: *If there is an error, the return value is -1. For example, the function fails if hWnd is an invalid window handle or lpMsg is an invalid pointer.* Neither of those conditions can occur here and so return value is never -1. Raymond explains: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/03/22/10404367.aspx  Taking advantage of that lets you greatly simplify the code.

Comment: I'd have thought you'd have been happy to learn that, rather than dismissive. I know that I have appreciated the many times that you have taught me something.

Comment: I have read that article before, I just did not remember that particular detail this time.  I don't write message loops very often, and when I do I usually don't use `GetMessage()` for them.

Comment: I don't understand why you wrote in that tone: "Fine, whatever".

Comment: I had my reasons, they don't need to be broadcasted here. I'll leave it at that.

Comment: I don't know if I learned it from documentation or trial, but your `GetMessage` call is quite enough to create the message queue (`PeekMessage` is not required) (I know what is suggested in PostThreadMessage's documentation). Additionally, docs suggest `PostQuitMessage` instead of directly posting a `WM_QUIT`.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: any user32 call, including `GetMessage()`, will create the message queue if needed. It is generally good practice to create the message queue ahead of time before you start receiving messages, hence the use of `PeekMessage()`. And yes, `PostQuitMessage()` will not work in this situation since `WM_QUIT` is being posted by another thread, hense the use of `PostThreadMessage()`.

Comment: @David - The calling thread is the same thread in this example.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: it is the same thread **class**, but it is not the same thread **context**. `Stop()` is meant to be called by other thread contexts, especially the one that owns this thread object.  `Stop()` is not called by `Execute()`, so `PostQuitMessage()` will not work in this example.

Answer (score 6):

Your message loop is a busy loop. You should use `GetMessage` instead of `PeekMessage`. That's because `GetMessage` blocks until messages are added to the queue.

You note in comments  that `GetMessage` blocks which breaks your termination code. Deal with that by posting a message to the thread after terminating it. Either `WM_NULL` as a general wake up, or `WM_QUIT` as an explicit instruction to quit the message loop.

Comment: Thanks, GetMessage() is excellent from performance point of view, but has a major problem, Thread cannot be terminated with that one! 
  It seems "Terminated" does not occur when I call  th.Terminate ;

Comment: - *"need to use GetMessage*" - It's not compulsory, `WaitMessage` can be used to block when `PeekMessage` returns false.

Comment: @Sertac Yes, need is too strong. That said, Wait/Peek is hardly to be preferred.

Comment: @Tom So don't use Terminate... you have a message loop, post a message instead.

Comment: thanks excellent help, code works now. However I will give a credit to the one that has a complete code, sorry for that..

Comment: That's fine. I'm much more of an explain using words kind of an answerer. I prefer to try to explain why rather than just present code without explanation. But if you find it easier to understand code then that's cool.